# equals method in java

Tags: java, equals

I have read about the `equals()` method in java. I've heard that it compares based just on value. But then why is it returning false for my case below where the value is the same but the types are different?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s1="compare";
        StringBuffer s2=new StringBuffer("compare");
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));  //false 
    }
}
```

Comment: You're effectively asking if your apple s1 is equal to the banana s2

Answer (score 11):

A `String` instance cannot be equal to a `StringBuffer` instance.

Look at the implementation :

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
if (this == anObject) {
    return true;
}
if (anObject instanceof String) { // this condition will be false in your case
    String anotherString = (String)anObject;
    int n = count;
    if (n == anotherString.count) {
    char v1[] = value;
    char v2[] = anotherString.value;
    int i = offset;
    int j = anotherString.offset;
    while (n-- != 0) {
        if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

In theory you can have an `equals` implementation that may return true when comparing two objects not of the same class (not in the `String` class though), but I can't think of a situation where such an implementation would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

`String` is different from `StringBuffer`. Use `toString()` to convert it to a `String`.

```
String s1="compare";
StringBuffer s2=new StringBuffer("compare");
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Eran is right you can't compair two diffrent objects using equals . If you really wants to do that then use `toString()` on StringBuffer

```
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `equals()` method belongs to `Object`.

From the [Java docs for Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

So basically:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

If you have a `String` and a `StringBuffer` they would not be equal to each other.

They might have the same value, but they aren't equal, have a look at the `instanceOf()` method.

Comment: Ok then why it is returning true.  String str="compare";
  String str1=new String("compare");
  System.out.println(str.equals(str1));

Comment: Because they are both `String`s, `StringBuffer` is a different class.