# Stack overflow error in a simple equals method?(Eclipse)

Tags: java, stack-overflow

so I'm doing an assignment in my computer science class and I am almost done but I am having trouble with the code. It works fine until I reach the equals method. This is code for an ArrayList object called a Document that we had to make. The problem is a StackOverFlow error coming from my 85th line of code which is in this small method:

```
public boolean equals(Document other) {
    return this.equals(other);
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well, equals() calls equals(), which calls equals(), etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [equals method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805123/equals-method-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Your equals implementation is wrong. Here is an example of correct implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Document)) {
        return false;
    }
    Document that = (Document) o;
    return Objects.equals(title, that.title); // compare all necessary fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a wrong implementation of the equals method. You should be comparing the instance variables of the Document objects.

eg

```
class Document{

  String docName; // initalised during constructor call

public boolean equals(Document other) {
     return this.docName.equals(other.docName);
}

}
```